# How to attach file while sending email in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I tried to send email using laravel smtp,

```
 Mail::send('mail', $data, function($message)  use ($request){
     $message->to($request->input('email'), 'Than Htut')->subject
        ($request->input('subject'));
     $message->attach($request->input('resume'));
     $message->from('myemail@gmail.com','My Name');
  });
  echo "HTML Email Sent. Check your inbox.";
```

the problem is showing like this

> Swift_IoException
>   Unable to open file for reading

But if i use attachData like this

```
  Mail::send('mail', $data, function($message)  use ($request){
     $message->to($request->input('email'), 'Than Htut')->subject
        ($request->input('subject'));
     $message->attachData($request->input('resume'), "haha.pdf");
     $message->from('myemail@gmail.com','My Name');
  });
  echo "HTML Email Sent. Check your inbox.";
```

its work, but cant open file. ,
[image]
Here is my fronend part,

```
<form class="uk-form-stacked" action="{{ url('jobseekers/send') }}" method="post" id="cv_mail_data">
                    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                    <input type="hidden" name="cv_no" value="{{ $jobseekers->id }}">




  <input type="text" placeholder="To" name="email" class="md-input" multiple>
  <input type="text" placeholder="To" name="subject" class="md-input" multiple>
  <input type="file" name="resume" accept="application/pdf,application/vnd.ms-excel" />



                             <div class="uk-grid" data-uk-grid-margin>
                                <div class="uk-width-medium-1-1 parsley-row">
                                    <textarea id="wysiwyg_tinymce" name="cover_letter" cols="30"
                                              rows="20"></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                Create
                            </button>
```

please guide me, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, where's your `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute in your form?
And second, for retrieving files on laravel you use the file method `$request->file('your-file');`.

Comment: i added enctype and tried   $message->attachData($request->file('resume'), 'invoice.pdf'); like this again, its still cant open. any idea sir, anyway thank you so much for answer.

Comment: Hmm, I have never tried sending the file directly from a form to an email, I don't think you can send the input as a parameter directly, maybe you could try first saving it on server and then sending the email with the path of the saved file.

Comment: $file = $request->file('resume'); $file->move('destination-path', 'file-name'); And then on attach data send the path of the file.

Comment: yeah, it could be possible , first save into the server and then use that desitination-path, i will try it out. Thanks agian sir.